# Wrong Time and Date with MariaDB mysql

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I've got a problem with my mariadb the time and data are not correct i've set the Timezone that I wanted but there is no changes:

The wrong date and time
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s74s5.png)

The correct date and time
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GKDH.png)

Comment: How have you [set the timezone](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/issues/440#issuecomment-1156667621)? Edit the question to include details.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please check the system clock of the host where the MariaDB server is running. For some reason there is an offset of about four days.